# How change attributes to UAC?

Tags: uac, processstartinfo

I need change of properties of windows User Account Control.
(Program Name, File Origin, Verified Publisher)
Is This Possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to digitally sign your application.

**Before digitally signing:**

[image]

**After digitally signing:**

[image]

Yes, it means you'll have to buy a digital signing certificate.