# Change the program name of exe on UAC

Tags: c#, uac, signtool

I have an exe which when tried to run as administrator shows the program name as TestSampleConsoleSign.exe. Its a simple console application with hello world in it.

```
namespace TestSampleConsoleSign
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I have also changed the AssemblyTitle field in AssemblyInfo.cs to HelloWorld. But when UAC is enabled the program name still shows as TestSampleConsoleSign.exe instead of HelloWorld. I also tried to signtool by creating a digital certificate using this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx and signing my exe with following command

```
signtool sign /f test.pfx /p password /d HelloWorld TestSampleConsoleSign.exe
```

I found this solution on [How change attributes to UAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059210/how-change-attributes-to-uac) What am I missing? Is this mandatory- [How change attributes to UAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059210/how-change-attributes-to-uac)

Comment: You cannot self-sign the executable, you have to spend the money.

Comment: @HansPassant . Is there no other way to just change the Program name?

Answer (score 2):

First I confirm that changing `AssemblyTitle` in AssemblyInfo.cs is the correct place. Note that this field shows up as *File Description* in the properties details page of Windows Explorer. Maybe you want to double check whether your AssemblyTitle appears there, just to make sure that you have really triggered a rebuild.

Then I tried running a Console application like yours with different certificates and the following happened:

- Self-created certificate (like yours): UAC shows the program's executable name.
- "Official" certificate with a trusted root authority: UAC shows the file description (AssemblyTitle)

Funny though: even if I change the executable name to something containing "Setup", the UAC dialog was not shown. For the UAC dialog to be shown, I had to check the checkmark "Run as administrator". Running as administrator might be your default, if you have included an app.manifest file with such a setting.

Comment: I have changed the UAC setting for testing purpose and like you mentioned i right click and execute as run as administrator. Looks like as @HansPassant mentioned there is no way out to display the custom name on UAC. It needs a official certificate as you have said